# Convert VBScript code to javascript (i.e. JScript) code

Tags: javascript, vbscript, jscript

how do we convert following vbscript to javascript?

```
<script type="text/vbscript">

  Function SayHello()
    MsgBox "Hello"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = "&H80000002"
uninstallRegKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
stdRegPro = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\default:StdRegProv"

Set objReg=GetObject(stdRegPro)

objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, uninstallRegKey, arrSubKeys
MsgBox arrSubKeys

  End Function

</script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Lok.

Comment: Do you mean *JScript* used in the Windows Script Host (cscript/wscript), or *JavaScript* run in browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, if you use JScript (Microsoft's implementation of Javascript for Windows) and some information e.g.

1. [Calling WMI Methods with JScript](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/calling-wmi-methods-jscript)
2. [Troubles with WMI in JScript](http://blog.vyvojar.cz/tom/archive/2004/08/30/1622.aspx)

(found by googling "jscript wmi").

Evidence:

```
function showUnInstall() {
    var HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
    var uninstallRegKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";
    var stdRegPro = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/default:StdRegProv";
    var objReg = GetObject(stdRegPro);

    var mEnumKey = objReg.Methods_.Item("EnumKey");
    var ipEnumKey = mEnumKey.InParameters.SpawnInstance_();
    ipEnumKey.hDefKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    ipEnumKey.sSubKeyName = uninstallRegKey;

    var mGetStringValue = objReg.Methods_.Item("GetStringValue");
    var ipGetStringValue = mGetStringValue.InParameters.SpawnInstance_();
    ipGetStringValue.hDefKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    ipGetStringValue.sValueName = "DisplayName";

    var opEnumKey = objReg.ExecMethod_(mEnumKey.name, ipEnumKey);
    if (0 === opEnumKey.ReturnValue) {
        var aNames = opEnumKey.sNames.toArray();
        for ( var i = 0; i < aNames.length; ++i) {
            ipGetStringValue.sSubKeyName = uninstallRegKey + "\\" + aNames[i];
            var opGetStringValue = objReg.ExecMethod_(mGetStringValue.name, ipGetStringValue);
            if (0 === opGetStringValue.ReturnValue) {
                WScript.Echo(opGetStringValue.sValue);
            } else {
                WScript.Echo("ERROR: GetStringValue.ReturnValue =", opGetStringValue.ReturnValue);
            }
        }
    } else {
        WScript.Echo("ERROR: EnumKey.ReturnValue =", opEnumKey.ReturnValue);
    }
}
```

output:

```
cscript 26907078.js
7-Zip 4.65
ActiveState ActiveTcl 8.5.2.0
ERROR: GetStringValue.ReturnValue = 1
Adobe Flash Player 15 Plugin
ERROR: GetStringValue.ReturnValue = 1
CMake 2.8, a cross-platform, open-source build system
Acrobat.com
...
```

Comment: Working !! Just a little change. Instead of var objReg = GetObject(stdRegPro); I did var objReg = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator"); Because it was throwing error "JavaScript runtime error: 'GetObject' is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Javascript does not have access to the registry.

---

This is not entirely accurate, I remember. A Node.js webserver running on Windows with NPM tools does have access, but only to that on the server it's running on. however, client-side javascript does not have access to the registry.